# Update to php5.3 breaks connecting to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I just updated php to 5.3 and can no longer connect to my remote mysql server. I get the following errors:

```
mysqli_connect(): OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2000): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication
```

It seems this has to do with the new mysqlnd driver. Is there a way to force it to use the old libmysql driver. Also, reverting to php5.2.11 doesn't seem to fix the issue which seems to work for most people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I typed up a long cool response but someone better than me already has answered it.  The tldr; of this response is recompile your php for your application.

http://news.php.net/php.internals/43535

Ionut G. Stan schrieb:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: OK packet 6 bytes 
>   shorter than expected in {filename} on line 18
>   Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: mysqlnd cannot 
>   connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication in {filename} on line 18

This says everything. You cannot use old authentication with mysqlnd.

Upgrade you server passwords to the more recent and more secure 
authentication method or recompile PHP with libmysql (MySQL Client 
Library) support. Check ./configure --help | grep -C3 mysql and 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php .

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/old-client.html says:

> Reset the password to pre-4.1 style for
>   each user that needs to use a pre-4.1
>   client program. This can be done using
>   the SET PASSWORD statement and the
>   OLD_PASSWORD() function:
>
> mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
>       -> 'some_user'@'some_host' = OLD_PASSWORD('newpwd'); Alternatively,
>   use UPDATE and FLUSH PRIVILEGES:
>
> mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password
>   = OLD_PASSWORD('newpwd')
>       -> WHERE Host = 'some_host' AND User = 'some_user'; mysql> FLUSH
>   PRIVILEGES; Substitute the password
>   you want to use for “newpwd” in the
>   preceding examples. MySQL cannot tell
>   you what the original password was, so
>   you'll need to pick a new one.
>
> Tell the server to use the older
>   password hashing algorithm:
>
> Start mysqld with the --old-passwords
>   option.

There are many more options on this page....

Comment: I believe the php language / mysql_connect function will be dropping support for the OLD PASSWORD authentication as of php5.3. this is the problem I seem to be dealing with. the server runs php5.2.11 and uses the old 16 byte password encryption while the client is expecting the new 41 byte password encryption. when i try to change the password using SET PASSWORD, it still gives me a 16 byte password

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://rabaix.net/en/articles/2009/09/21/php5-3-and-mysqlnd-authentication-issue).

Just reset the user's password.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypassword');
```

Comment: this gave me the same 16 byte encryption i already had, not the 41 byte one i would like

Comment: i've read somewhere that there is a setting that would do this but i've had no luck finding it